# The probability the third yellow is drawn before the third blue marble?

Tags: probability

There are $3$ blue and $7$ yellow marbles in an urn. Marbles are drawn one at a time without replacement. What is the probability the third yellow is drawn before the third blue marble?

I did:

$$\frac{4!}{2!\cdot2!}\cdot\frac{7\cdot6\cdot3\cdot2\cdot5}{10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6}=\frac{1}{4}$$

However, the correct answer is $0.917$

Comment: The first three draws could all be yellow, or the first three could be 1 blue and 2 yellows, followed by another yellow, or the first four could be 2 blue and 2 yellows, followed by another yellow. You could find the probabilities of those three options, and add them together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine five have been drawn.  Then exactly one of blue, yellow will have been drawn at least $3$ times.  Thus this is the same as asking "what is the probability that in the first $5$ fewer than $3$ blue marbles will be seen".  We can compute that by cases:

Case I.  $0$ blue balls.  $$\binom 75\Bigg /\binom {10}5 = \frac {21}{252}$$

Case II.  $1$ blue ball.  $$\left( \binom 74 \times \binom 31\right)\Bigg /\binom {10}5=\frac {105}{252}$$

Case III $2$ blue balls $$\left( \binom 73 \times \binom 32\right)\Bigg/\binom {10}5=\frac {105}{252}$$

Combining, we see that the answer is $$\frac {21+105+105}{252}=\frac {231}{252}=0.91\overline {6}$$

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to compute the complement: the probability that the third blue marble is drawn before the third yellow marble.  (Obviously, there cannot be any ties.)  This is simply the probability that all three blue marbles are within the first five draws, which is

$$
\frac{\binom{5}{3}}{\binom{10}{3}} = \frac{1}{12}
$$

Then the desired probability is just $1$ minus that, or $11/12$.

Comment: An elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are only 10 ways of getting 3 blues before 3 yellows

BBB, BBYB, BYBB, YBBB, BBYYB, BYBYB, YBBYB, BYYBB, YBYBB and YYBBB.

There are 120 different color combinations $10!/(3!*7!)$
Hence the probability is $(120 - 10)/120 = .917$